# Does Edge for Mac render the same way as Edge for Windows?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

Edge for Mac exists now. Both the Windows & Mac versions are based on Chromium (from what I understand) and they both seem to be on the same release schedule & version.

I can't seem to find this documented anywhere, from what I can tell only the Windows version is found on sites like caniuse. Is it possible that these browsers can be considered as one, as in a site built for Edge on Mac could be expected to render the same on Edge for Windows?

Asking because I need to test a site out on Edge but it would be great to avoid using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, I think their results will be different. Although they use the same rendering engine, the source code of different platforms will be different (based on development and design concepts).

This shows that although the underlying rendering performance and operating system compatibility will become similar between them, there will still be a certain gap in actual experience.

Comment: That's what I would expect too, just interesting that they have the same release schedule.